# Connection between IP camera and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ip-camera

I want to get live Stream of IP Camera by using Android App. I dunno where to get the IP address of Camera and how to connect to the Android App. Anyone can help me with this or Guide me that how can I develop an App so I can get the Live stream of IP Camera using their IP address. thanks

Answer (score 0):

most network camera manufacturers have a default IP address for their camera but some will accept an IP address assigned to it via DHCP instead. for example, with axis cameras the default IP address is 192.168.0.90 unless it comes into contact with a DHCP server then it will accept whatever address is assigned to it. you can always change this later.

once you find the IP address use a browser access the web interface and make configuration changes and check your live view.

depending on the camera manufacturer, there is likely an Android App that is designed for your make/model. i hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: its GOQ IP Camera. it has its own app but I want to connect it to my app as well. the problem is that I build one application for smart room and one of its feature is to access to cctv camera..